# can I send some nears from my .testnet account to .near account?

Tags: nearprotocol, near

Problem:
I want to create .near account and for this purpose, I must to send 0.1 near to  my implicit account.

I have tried to send near, the transaction has been successful but my implicit account was not created
[transaction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pR3MX.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't transfer NEAR tokens from the testnet to the mainnet. They're different networks with different purposes.

testnet money is 'fake' :)

Please read this for further info on how to fund your wallet (1st deposit):
https://wiki.near.org/creating-a-near-wallet#funding-your-account-

Or for more general info on creating your account on NEAR (both testnet and mainnet are covered):
https://docs.near.org/docs/develop/basics/create-account

Answer (score 3):

No. Testnet tokens are for testing purposes and don't have any real value